# Unable to run clara rules clojure program from eclipse

Tags: clojure

I am trying to learn clara rules - clojure which is present in "http://www.clara-rules.org/docs/firststeps/"

```
(ns with-mongo.clara.example
   (:require [clara.rules :refer :all]))

(defrecord SupportRequest [client level])

(defrecord ClientRepresentative [name client])

(defrule is-important
  "Find important support requests."
  [SupportRequest (= :high level)]
  =>
  (println "High support requested!"))

(defrule notify-client-rep
  "Find the client representative and request support."
  [SupportRequest (= ?client client)]
  [ClientRepresentative (= ?client client) (= ?name name)]
  =>
  (println "Notify" ?name "that"  
          ?client "has a new support request!"))
```

Executing the following in REPL

```
 (-> (mk-session 'with-mongo.clara.example)
     (insert (->ClientRepresentative "Alice" "Acme")
                  (->SupportRequest "Acme" :high))
          (fire-rules))
```

But what I get in eclipse is
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: fire-rules in this context, compiling:(C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\form-init8304513432405616575.clj:1:2)

Does anyone has any details on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I was facing was due to the version mismatches

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [com.novemberain/monger "3.0.0-rc2"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [com.cerner/clara-rules "0.19.0"]])
```

I was using 1.6.0 for clojure and after updating to clojure "1.7.0". Clara rules are getting triggered.

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [com.novemberain/monger "3.0.0-rc2"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [com.cerner/clara-rules "0.19.0"]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not `require`d `clara.rules` in your REPL beforehand.  E.g. run

```
(require '[clara.rules :refer :all]))
```

first.  (or run your own `ns` there first - that depends on how you want to run/use the REPL and what eclipse allows you to use (non-eclipse-user here))

So why does it complain about `fire-rules` and not `mk-session`?  That is due to the way the threading macro `->` works.  If you `macroexpand` your code, that throws, you will see, that `fire-rules` is actually the first function called.

Comment: (ns with-mongo.clara.example
   (:require [clara.rules :refer :all])) -- these first two lines has those I beleive?

Comment: So when we load the  file in REPL, those should be included right?

Comment: to add when I specifically (require '[clara.rules :refer :all])
FileNotFoundException Could not locate clara/rules__init.class or clara/rules.clj on classpath:   clojure.lang.RT.load (RT.java:443)

Comment: :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [com.novemberain/monger "3.0.0-rc2"]
                 [ring "1.4.0"]
                 [ring/ring-json "0.4.0"]
                 [compojure "1.4.0"]
                 [com.cerner/clara-rules "0.19.0"]])